# AngularJs & angular-local-storage - Changing page / url keeps storage?

Tags: angularjs, angular-local-storage

When I change pages the local storage is displayed on the new page, even though the url has changed. If i set the localStorage for site somesite.com, no matter where i navigate, data will be there till i clear/remove it!

I have tried this:
The ID is in the url `/games/25/` and passed as a  `ng-init="id = 25"` variable

So with this 'feature' how do i prevent localStorage data being overwritten?
Should i scrap this method altogether, is there a better way?

Comment: localStorage is domain specific, not url specific. Please show how you are using all of this because `ng-init` is only used for `ng-repeat` aliases not for general use and there is something wrong in you use of localStorage

Comment: so how do i prefix localStorage to be url specific? That's the question. ng-init works fine the way it is as php is passing the data to angular. Can this not be a general question?

Comment: You don't do it as url specific...make it specific to the data being stored. Use $routeParams or $stateParams depending on your router to keep track or the `id` that is passed to controller from your `ng-init`

Comment: Are you suggesting i use a angular router, how would that help with localStorage?

Comment: I assumed you were using a router since url's are changing and angular is typically used in single page applications